# Unable to reload script when navigated to another page in next js

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am trying to reload the ad script on each page, but it only works when I refresh the page. So, I see the ad showing only when the page is refreshed.. Have a look at the code:

```
import { usePathname } from "next/navigation";
import { useEffect } from "react";
export function LoadAd() {
  useEffect(() => {
const pathname = usePathname();
    const script = document.createElement("script");
    script.src =
      "//pl22500737.profitablegatecpm.com/1c8566c67a4bf36055e7f55caabeabb0/invoke.js";
    script.async = true;
    document.body.appendChild(script);
    return () => {
      script.remove();
    };
  }, [pathname]);
  return (
   null
  );
}
```

In another component where the ad will show:

```
const Home = () => {
      <div
        className="mx-auto max-[350px]:hidden w-[300px] h-72 max-h-72"
        id="container-1c8566c67a4bf36055e7f55caabeabb0"></div>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

I'm importing the LoadAd component in the app's root directory (page.js). I have tried using next's usePathname to force reload, but it did not work.

If you want to see the issue live, what is happening here is the live version:
(https://calculatecgpa.com)

Go to the fact of the day page and come back home. You will see the ad below is not showing.

Answer (score 0):

First of all usePathname() hook must be use with in the client component so use "use client"; at the top of the LoadAd component.

As as per next documentation Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. so the usePathname() hook can be called outside of the useEffect() hook.

so the function can be written as

```
"use client";
import {usePathname} from "next/navigation";
import {useEffect} from "react";

export function LoadAd() {
    const pathname = usePathname();
    useEffect(() => {
        const script = document.createElement("script");
        script.src = "//pl22500737.profitablegatecpm.com/1c8566c67a4bf36055e7f55caabeabb0/invoke.js";
        script.async = true;
        document.body.appendChild(script);
        return () => {
            script.remove();
        };
    }, [pathname]);
    return null;
}
```

Try this!

Comment: Tried as you said but still the ad is not showing.

Comment: This will work send me what is the error and snap of your code.